# installing kubectl in GCP compute engine using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, kubectl

Need to add multiple commands in `metadata_startup_script` in `terraform` script to launch `compute engine` instance in `GCP`

Following is my code

```
  metadata_startup_script = "curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" ; chmod +x kubectl ; sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin"
```

`terraform plan` shows below error

```
   Error: Missing newline after argument

  on main.tf line 58, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
  58: metadata_startup_script = "curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" ; chmod +x kubectl ; sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin"

  An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

Any suggestions to resolve this ? The task is to install `kubectl` once a `compute engine` is launched using below commands

```
   curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" 
   chmod +x kubectl 
   sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin"
```

Comment: quotes in the following line could be the issue, did you try to not use the second one?

metadata_startup_script = "curl -LO "https:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 solution

1. Escape the double quote "

```
  metadata_startup_script = "curl -LO \"https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl\" ; chmod +x kubectl ; sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin"
```

2. Write your script in multiline inside the TF file

```
metadata_startup_script = <<SCRIPT
   curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" 
   chmod +x kubectl 
   sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin
SCRIPT
```